# Copying vector and remaining the memory adress of the members

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stl, pass-by-value

I try to read in some data of teams and players and change the data.
The Player class members have pointers to the teams from the Team class, while the Teams have a playerlist filled with pointers to the players.

The problem comes with the readin()-function which reads in the team and player data from a txt.file and returns a vector of teams. After the readin-process the pointers created in the readin-process seem to direct to wrong addresses.

So reading out data from the vector of teams returned by the read-in function is not the same anymore than reading out the data from the pointers created in the read-in function.

Here is the general structur of the classes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Player;
class Team
{
public:
    std::vector<Player*> getplayerlist(){
        return playerlist;
    }
    void setteamname(std::string x){
        teamname = x;
    }
    std::string getteamname(){
        return teamname;
    }
    void Team::addPlayer(Player* x){
        playerlist.emplace_back(x);
    };



private:
    std::vector<Player*> playerlist;
    std::string teamname;

};

class Player
{
public:
    Team* getpteam(){
        return pteam;
    }
    void setpteam(Team* x){
        pteam = x;
    }
    void setinformation(std::string x, int y){
        name= x;
        id = y;
      }

private: 
    int id;
    std::string name;
    Team* pteam;
};
```

And here is the structure of the read-in function

```
vector<Team> readin(){

//some readin stuff

//if the line contains the teamname

Team team;
team.setteamID_(a);
team.setteamname_(word2);
Teamvector.emplace_back(team);

//if the line contains player data
//add the player to the team created before     

Player* player = new Player();
player->setinformation_(b, word1, lname, str, &Teamvector[a-1]);
Teamvector[a-1].addPlayer(player);

return Teamvector;
}
```

But if i compare the addresses of `&Teamvektor[0]` and

```
vector <Team> team = readin();
&team[0]
```

they are different. How can i "remain" the adress of the stored teams ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `std::vector` by value: this means container is being copied, thus elements have same values but different addresses in memory.

There are few ways how to handle this. For example:

1. Create container and fill it in your method:

   ```
   std::vector<Team>   v;

   void readin_fillVector( vector<Team>& v) {
     //..  v.push_back( team);
   }
   ```
2. Pass iterator

   ```
   void readin_fillVector( std::back_insert_iterator< std::vector<Team> > it) {
     //..  (*it)++ = team;
   }
   ```

Comment: i guessed this is the problem, but could'nt figure out how to solve this problem. Tried it by return a vector<Team*> insted but this failed, too

Comment: I did the changes, but now i get error C2664: 'Team::Team(const Team &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'Team *' to 'const Team &' \xmemory0 
 It comes from the line v.emplace_back(team) i figured out. EDIT: i solve it, had changed my Team team to Team* team in my tests. Thx now it works like it should be

Comment: please create a new question with a new code and  description in case of new problems